# Cannot send mail through SQL Server sp_send_dbmail. Certificate error

Tags: sql-server, certificate, senddbmail

Below is the error message I see in windows event log. No errors while executing sp_send_dbmail

1. Exception Information
   ===================
   Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Common.BaseException
   Message: There was an error on the connection. Reason: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.), connection parameters: Server Name: LAM90DB01, Database Name: msdb
   Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
   TargetSite: Void OpenConnection(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.SqlConnectionInfo)
   HelpLink: NULL
   Source: DatabaseMailEngine
   HResult: -2146232832

## StackTrace Information

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.DataAccess.ConnectionManager.OpenConnection(SqlConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.IMailProcess.QueueItemProcesser.ProcessQueueItems(String dbName, String dbServerName, Int32 lifetimeMinimumSec, LogLevel loggingLevel, Byte[] encryptionKey, Int32 connectionTimeout)

Exception Type: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
NativeErrorCode: -2146893019
ErrorCode: -2147467259
Message: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: NULL
HelpLink: NULL
Source: NULL
HResult: -2147467259

Comment: That message -- "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" -- typically means a client is attempting an encrypted connection to a SQL instance and the SQL instance is using a self-signed certificate.

Comment: There is no certificate installed on SQL Server. Verified through SQL Configuration manager and also through this script:
 SELECT
    db.name,
    db.is_encrypted,
    dm.encryption_state,
    dm.percent_complete,
    dm.key_algorithm,
    dm.key_length
FROM
    sys.databases db
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_database_encryption_keys dm
        ON db.database_id = dm.database_id
  where db.is_encrypted = 1

Comment: That script has nothing to do with the certificate used to encrypt connections. The only place to look is Configuration Manager or the registry

Comment: Where do you look in registry and what do you look there? Thanks